# How do I change the mode indicators for evil-mode in the spaceline mode line package?

Tags: spacemacs, evil, mode-line

The mode line shows `<N>` or `<I>` or `<V>` and I would like it to show `NORMAL`, `INSERT`, `VISUAL`, etc.

I'm new to Emacs so my Elisp skills are non-existent.

Comment: How do you get the `<N>/<I>/<V>` in mode line when using spaceline? I use spacemacs+spaceline, they are just colors not `<N>/<I>/<V>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify how the mode-line shows the evil state by setting the corresponding tag variable. You'll need these lines somewhere in your emacs init file.

```el
(setq evil-normal-state-tag "NORMAL")
(setq evil-insert-state-tag "INSERT")
(setq evil-visual-state-tag "VISUAL")
```

Comment: (setq evil-emacs-state-tag "EMACS")
for emacs state